# Can someone explain this proof of the product property of square roots?

Tags: proof-verification

I'm studying a proof of the **product property of square roots**. I can follow it up to statement 8, but I can't make sense of how the last statement, 9, follows from the previous ones. I have transcribed the proof below.

> **Product property of square roots**: If $a$ and $b$ are real numbers such that $a \geq 0$ and $b \geq 0$, then $\sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b} = \sqrt{ab}$.
>
> 1. $a \geq 0 \hbox{ and } b \geq 0.$
>
>    Given.
> 2. There is a unique non-negative number $\sqrt{a}$ such that $(\sqrt{a})^2 = a$. There is a unique non-negative number $\sqrt{b}$ such that $(\sqrt{b})^2 = b$.
>
>    Theorem 37.
> 3. $(\sqrt{a})^2(\sqrt{b})^2 = ab$
>
>    Multiplication property of equality.
> 4. $(\sqrt{a})^2(\sqrt{b})^2= (\sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b})^2$
>
>    $a^nb^n = (a\cdot b)^n$
> 5. $(\sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b})^2 = ab$
>
>    Transitive property of equality.
> 6. $\sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b} \geq 0$
>
>    The product of non-negative numbers is non-negative.
> 7. $ab \geq 0$
>
>    The product of non-negative numbers is non-negative.
> 8. There is a unique non-negative number $\sqrt{ab}$ such that $(\sqrt{ab})^2 = ab$
>
>    Theorem 37.
> 9. $\sqrt{ab} = \sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$
>
>    Theorem 37, steps 5, 6, and 8.

<sub><sup>(Pearson, H. R and Allen, F. B. (1970). *Modern Algebra - A Logical Approach (Book I)*. Boston: Ginn and Company, p. 508.)</sup></sub>

**Edit:** I was asked to include Theorem 37, which is used in the proof. It is reproduced below.

> **Theorem 37:**
>
> If $a$ is a non-negative real number, then there is a unique non-negative real number denoted by $\sqrt{a}$ such that $(\sqrt{a})^2$.

I think a few steps are skipped from statement 8 to statement 9. I can see that

$$(\sqrt{ab})^2 = (\sqrt{a} \cdot \sqrt{b})^2$$

due to the transitive property of equality and statement 5, but I can't see how to go from there to 9 without assuming

$$(a^2  = b^2) \land (a \geq 0) \land (b \geq 0) \implies a = b. $$

And I can't figure out how to prove this last statement, although it seems to make intuitive sense. But maybe it's something else I'm missing.

Comment: The part you think is missing is essentially statement 8.

Comment: The statement 8 says that if something non-negative squared is $ab$ then it's $\sqrt{ab}$, but number 5 says that $(\sqrt a\sqrt b)^2 = ab$, and 6 says that $\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$ is non-negative. What's the problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let $x=\sqrt{a}\cdot\sqrt{b}$. Step $5$ shows that $x^2=ab$. Step $6$ shows that $x\ge 0$. Step $8$ says that there is exactly one number with these properties, and it’s denoted by $\sqrt{ab}$. Since $x$ has these properties, and $\sqrt{ab}$ is a name of the only number with these properties, it must be the case that $x=\sqrt{ab}$, which is what Step $9$ says.

Comment: Thanks, the proof makes a lot more sense now. I've identified my stumbling block to be the unique existential quantification, which I haven't encountered before.

Comment: @Calculemus: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Let's just prove the last statement in your question. Let $a,b \ge 0$ and assume $a^2 = b^2$.

Assume for the sake of contradiction $a \ne b$. WLOG, $a > b$, so $a = b+x$ for some real $x > 0$.

Now
$$
a^2 = (b+x)^2 = b^2 + 2bx + x^2
$$
and since $a^2 = b^2$, subtracting it from both sides yields $$0 = 2bx + x^2 = x(2b+x).$$ Hence, either $x=0$ or $x = -2b$. But $b \ge 0$, so if $x = -2b$ then $x \le 0$, which contradicts $x > 0$. Then, $x=0$, which also contradicts $x > 0$.

Hence $a=b$.

Comment: Thanks, I seem to be able to follow this, and it seems to be enough to prove the original property. WLOG in this case means that the same thing could be proven for $b>a$?

Comment: @Calculemus yes...